# Unable to create SharePoint List from Excel data due to JSON parse error

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I was trying to create a SharePoint List from Excel data, I have around 600 rows and 250 columns. I get the error
[image]

Then I tried to feed the data less then 250 columns, strangely it works. I tried to examine the data exchange between browser and the cloud, but I have no clue what was happen.

What could this possibly the problem?

Comment: You are most probably hitting the 8000 bytes limit for the list https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Column based on the number of columns that you have

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue creating a SharePoint List according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa. It can support up to **20,000 rows**.
I've just tested with 300 rows without any problem.

Another thing worth looking at:

- Maybe there're a few rows after those 250 rows that the data type isn't consistent?
- As the guide in the link above said, it's best to run "Format as Table" in the excel, and make sure the column formats are consistent (number, text, etc.)
- You can also export the excel to CSV format and import it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will give a try